# AttributeError: 'MainRouter' object has no attribute '_disabled_count'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am creating a kivy app where I have used router showing this error-

AttributeError: 'MainRouter' object has no attribute '_disabled_count'

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused by Kivy version. The latest version of Kivy-1.10.1 has some bug which is causing the problem. The older version seems fine!

Answer (score 9):

I got this too but fixed it using super.  Call the default init from within your new init using

```
super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Cool. I will check that.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to remove the "**kwargs"  from the init:  `super().__init__()`